# How to return JSON data on successfull async ajax request in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I am submitting a form using ajax, How can I pass successful data back to the submission page? I am submitting a transaction over the TRON network so the response is an array with the transaction ID that I would like to return to the submission page.

In php I would use -

```
$exchange_array = array(
     'success' => '1',
);
  
echo json_encode($exchange_array);
```

Then in JS

```
var success = data['success'];
```

But now I am returning data in JS like follows -

```
 $(".form").submit(function(e) {
      var url = "submit.php"; 
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: new FormData(this), 
           contentType: false,      
           cache: false,            
           processData:false, 
           success: function (data) {

               // check if successful and return txid

            } 
      }); 
       e.preventDefault();
   });
```

Submit.php -

```
const sentTx= async () => {
    const tx = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.tradeExchangeTokens(exchangeID, tokenName, tokenAmountSold, tokenAmountExpected, ownerAddress)
    const signedtxn =  await tronWeb.trx.multiSign(tx, privateKey, 0);
    const receipt =  tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedtxn);
    var txid = signedtxn.txID;
  
    // Return txid to ajax request result
};
sentTx();
```

So how would I return the txid to the ajax request on a successful request?

Comment: Try this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @ChrisP thanks but im looking to encode a JSON string in JS to pass back to my ajax request, this is for parsing JSON correct?

Comment: Yes, correct....

Answer (score 0):

You may be misunderstanding the concept of asynchrony in javascript.
`success` method for ajax is not intended for returning anymore. It can run callback - a function, that a doin something.

For example you can write a function that doin something with data:

```js
var myDataReader = function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

and call it from success:

```js
$.ajax
  ...
  success: myDataReader
```

Comment: I submit forms in ajax  and return data in PHP all the time, youre saying this isnt possible in JS?

Comment: Yes, you are thinking about succes method as sync function, that returns value, but it is a async function and can run callback. If you want a doing something with data, returned from php, write function and call it from success method.

Comment: Ok, if the data to be returned is in JS though how would I do that? Is there a better method I should be using all together? Im mainly a php dev so JS isnt my strong suit.. The transaction needs to be submitted the way I posted so just need a way to check confirmation.

Comment: Just saw you updated your answer, i'll try using a JS function like you recommended.

Comment: When I try your example I get myDataReader is not defined, not sure Im using it correctly , Do I put the function in the JS file that executes the transaction or do both go in the form page?

Comment: For first try - write definition of function `myDataReader` before `$.ajax`.